# Grails upgrade from 2.3.5 to 2.5.6

Tags: grails, spring-security

I'm using Grails 2.3.5 with spring-security-core version 1.2.7.2. Now, I need to upgrade to Grails 2.5.6, but I'm facing some issues regarding spring security. Indeed,  I tried with spring-security-core:2.0.0, however I encountered the issue below:

```
error: cannot find symbol
[groovyc] import grails.plugin.springsecurity.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter;
[groovyc]                                    ^
[groovyc]   symbol:   class RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter
[groovyc]   location: package grails.plugin.springsecurity
```

Any idea ? What is the right version to use, or which modification should  I do in order to fix this issue ?

Comment: See [What's New in Version 2.0](https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/v2/guide/newInV2.html)